# Tkinter Canvas object not appearing

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I was trying to add a draggable window object in the tkinter canvas. It worked when there wasn't the 'obj' function but I want it to be there for specific purposes. Now, when I try to do it, no button pops up on the canvas.

```
from tkinter import *
import app

def obj(can,text):
    b1 = "up"
    xold, yold = None, None


    def main():
        global aaa
        global frame
        global text
        global drawing_area
        drawing_area = can


        drawing_area.create_window(50,50,tags='aaa',window=text)

        text.bind("<Motion>", motion)
        text.bind("<ButtonPress-1>", b1down)
        text.bind("<ButtonRelease-1>", b1up)



    def b1down(event):
        global b1
        b1 = "down"           


    def b1up(event):
        global b1, xold, yold
        b1 = "up"
        xold = None           
        yold = None

    def motion(event):
        global frame
        global aaa
        global text
        global drawing_area
        if b1 == "down":
            global xold, yold
            if xold is not None and yold is not None:
                            drawing_area.move('aaa',event.x,event.y)

            xold = event.x
            yold = event.y

root = Tk()
drawing_area = Canvas(root,height=500,width=700,bg='Blue')
text=Button(drawing_area,text='Test')
drawing_area.pack()
if __name__ == "__main__":
    obj(drawing_area,text)
```

Comment: Have you tried something as simple as adding a few print statements to validate whether functions you _think_ are being called are _actually_ being called?

Answer (score 0):

Your `obj` function defines three variables and four functions, but *does* nothing.

Try adding `main()` as the last line of your `obj()` definition.